# WPF MvvM DataGrid variable Columns through a IList of columns

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am searching about how to create variable number of columns in a DataGrid from the Ilist in MVVM way. The requirement I am working on is very big and also the number of rows and columns are not known  But I did not find satisfactory answers

Is there some one that had to do the samething ?

If there is no way of generating such columns, I know I can do that by binding DataGrid to a DataSet. Then I have one more problem; if I am using DataSet, how do I display different UI in different cells based on some parameter?

**Please help its very urgent requirement!!!!!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I haven't tried this myself, but I think you should be able to pull this off by creating a dynamic object, and binding to a list of MyDynamicObject. WPF supports binding to dynamic objects ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx)).
Theoretically it could work like this:

```
public List<dynamic> MyDynamicList {get; set;}

dynamic obj = new MyDynamicObject();
obj.DisplayCode = "Test";
obj.SomeProperty = "hello world";
MyDynamicList.Add(obj);
```

You will need to create MyDynamicObject by implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`and `DynamicMetaObject`. More on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff800651.aspx).

Hope this will put you in the right direction...